# How to do Solr search integration with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, solr5

I have solr on my local machine and its working fine when 
I am hitting this url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

but I am new in solr search and I don't know how to configure PHP and MySQL with Solr.

I am using windows8 and solr5.1.0.
If any one have command in `solr+php+mysql` then please suggest.

Comment: Could you able to make queries to your Solr from the address bar of your web browser?

Comment: See: [Using Solarium with SOLR for Search – Solarium and GUI](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-solarium-solr-search-solarium-gui/) and [Solarium Project](http://www.solarium-project.org/).

Comment: @alok Asking for tutorials is off-topic. Your question is too broad and opinion based. You should ask some specific question only (about programming). If you're beginner, you can consider using Drupal, it should be much easier. See: [Apache Solr installation and compatibility with Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/95897/1908).

Comment: I am a  magento developer not a drupal deloper. Is there any link for magento then please share....

Answer (score 4):

Simply and mainly you will need two native PHP functions:

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) -*I prefer to deal with Solr queries as JSON output*-

Here are a simple custom function in which you have to supply it with full URL query to your Solr such as `http://localhost:8080/solr/wak/select?q=SearchPool%3Aالصلاة&wt=json&indent=true` *of course it changed depending on your schema and the requirements of query*.

```
function readQuery($q){     
        $data = file_get_contents($q);
        return json_decode($data);
    }
```

The `readQuery` function returns a JSON object, *notice `wt=json` in the URL*, with the query results. For debugging and knowing how to access the objects properties you may use `var_dump`.